# Blogger Soho Theme Main Page Width Between Columns

Tags: html, css, blogger

My Blogger Soho theme main page has two columns listing the posts complete with pictures. The gaps between the columns are too close. May I know if there is a css code to improve that?

Sorry if this question has been answered as I could not find one after searching and I am a newbie in css.

https://retireby50sg.blogspot.com

Thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: Have you tried using the `margin` attribute, like `margin: 15px`? It might also be helpful if you post your code.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which are basically: go look at my site and fix it, are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move a [MCVE] into the question. Please see: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I did try to meddle with margin but I did not know which one to edit. I wanted to post my codes but I am not too sure which section to post for this one. I am a newbie and just starting out to learn. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your image width is going out of div so try to reduce the width of image. here is the css try this

```
.snippet-thumbnail img {
    width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It works!

Comment: Pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't post your code is so hard to give you a proper answer, but I could say you that you should open the CSS code about your theme and find the two columns tag or id or whatewer the theme uses, then you could use margin or padding property to make the gap between both bigger.

Use of margin and padding (Because you said you're a newbie hahahaha)

- Margin: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
- Padding:    https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did try to meddle with margin but I did not know which one to edit. I wanted to post my codes but I am not too sure which section to post for this one. I am a newbie and just starting out to learn. Thank you for your patience.